# What is the best way to store a formula in a database for a table driven formula?

Tags: java, database, database-design, sql

So I am changing my code over to a table driven formula system to make it sustainable in the long term.

So basically I have 5 foreign keys that will get me to a single formula to use. However I'm not quite sure how I should store the formula. At the moment I am just using a char(100) and parsing it in Java on retrieval. This seems risky though.

My formulas are quite simple (.9 * inputBoxA) but it just gives me a bad feeling doing it this way. Is there a standard for this or will I just have to push on?

Edit:
Let me explain my situation a bit more. I have 5 foreign keys all based on user input. One other input is a rate that the user gives. So based on the 5 FKs I want to do a calculation on this rate.

The formula will usually be (inputRate), (.9*inputRate), etc. But it can get a bit more complex (.9*(.6*inputRate-.1)) but still nothing too bad.

I will be retrieving the formulas from my database with a JPA query and process it in Java so the user should never directly see the formulas. However in the future new formulas may be necessary so I need some standard for others to be able to enter them.

Comment: what is "table driven formula system"? [Decision table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table)?

Comment: @gnat I suppose a decision table is what most resembles what I want. I'm not really having an issue on how to access the data though. It's how best to structure my end result so that my application can interpret it. Keep in mind I have approximately 1000 possible formulas and I need to be able to add formulas without any changes to the code.

Comment: Why do you have formulas and how do you use them, and what for? You should **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: Who is writing and reading these formulaes?

Comment: Your edit is not enough. Foreign key are an irrelevant implementation detail. What is the formula useful for? Who is typing it?

Comment: A formula is useful only when you have some evaluator on it. This brings semantics issues. What does your formula mean? How and where are the variables bound?

Comment: asking for "best" anything is automatically asking for opinions...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a matter of opinion. You might use postfix representation (à la [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), or even some [stack-oriented programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language)), or some [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) (specific to your expression language), or some [s-expr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) syntax, if you want some more compact representation. [JSON](http://json.org/) is probably a less compact textual representation but it is very widely used (and you've got many libraries to parse JSON); you could define your JSON format for your expression [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s.

You could also store a compressed form of your formula's representation in your database.

You might consider using some bytecode of some existing interpreter, e.g. [Lua](http://lua.org/), [Guile2](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), or even some [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) class with your own [class loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader), etc...

And perhaps you want to store [*closures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), not expressions.

You may want to embed an interpreter inside your application.

You need to learn more about programming languages (e.g. read Scott's book: [Programming Language Pragmatics](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/)), compilers (read the [dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition)) & [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) & interpreters & [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) ; if you know a bit of [Scheme](http://schemers.org/) or Lisp (and learning it thru [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) is not a loss of your time) I strongly recommend Queinnec's book [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html), giving a broad view of interpretation & compilation techniques.

[MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) is a standard for representation of mathematics, notably formulas (using XML). But it is not compact and not easy to parse, so very probably overkill to represent expressions.

[OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) is a standard for spreadsheet & word processing documents, so contains a notation for expressions (apparently related to MathML).

You can use some DBMS (from [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) to PostgresQL, MongoDB, MariaDB/MySQL) to store your formulas (as `TEXT` or [`BLOB`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) in SQL sense), you'll be able to store millions or billions of them (e.g. have some SQL `TABLE` containing them, one row per formula).

Don't forget to *document* the format of your persistent data, and the form of the "expressions" and/or "closures" in it. Even your advanced users could need to know that format and use it in some other way without having to reverse-engineer it.

Perhaps you are re-inventing [business rule management systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rule_management_system) or [expert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) (look into [CLIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS) & [JESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jess_%28programming_language%29)) or some [scripting language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) (then perhaps try to use an existing one, not invent your own) or [spreadsheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet) ...

I don't see any risk in storing your formulas as text, provided you define and **document very well the syntax of your formulas** (e.g. using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)) **and their semantics** (e.g. an [operational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics)); publish that documentation (advanced users would need to know about them). Parsing efficiently short formulas is not a real issue (the disk I/O or database access would probably be the bottleneck, more than the parsing of the formula) : you can write a simple [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) or use a [parsing expression grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar). Evaluating a formula is more difficult (and requires a semantics, and some [evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy)). You'll need some environment to deal with your variables and their [binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding)! Read also about [higher-order abstract syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_abstract_syntax). Don't forget to validate a formula before storing it.

You might even take a [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) approach and translate these formalas into a routine (or a method, or a class, etc...) or something runnable...